# Exporting tables to CSV on postgres without having to use 'Text to columns'

Tags: python, sql, excel, csv

I've been using the following script to export tables from redshift and postgres:

```
@export on;
@export set filename="D:\Users\files\filename.csv" CsvColumnDelimiter=";";
SELECT * FROM schemaname.tablename;
@export off;
```

This works well, but to get the data in separate columns I have to use the "Text to Columns" function in excel. I am looking for a script that will automate the "Text to Columns" step as I have over 700 tables. I've been searching for SQL and Python scripts that will do this, but haven't found anything so far.

Answer (score 0):

Excel is expecting a comma delimiter in the CSVs. You need to either change your delimiter, or change the default delimiter for Excel. You can do that in your [Region & Language](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21456/export-or-save-excel-files-with-pipe-or-other-delimiters-instead-of-commas/) settings.

Answer (score 0):

python has a builtin csv module.

```
import csv
with open('in.csv', 'r') as infp:
    with open('out.csv', 'w') as outfp:
        reader = csv.reader(infp, delimiter=';')
        writer = csv.writer(outfp, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            writer.writenow(row)
```

Should translate the delimiter. Look at [CSV](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for full details.

There's probably a better way of doing this.  On linux there are sed, awk, tr, etc that can do this in one arcane line. See  [8 examples to change the delimiter of a file in Linux](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/09/examples-how-to-change-delimiter-of-file-Linux.html).  But I don't know the windows equivalents, if there are any.